# how to specify custom validation for user details like telephone number, last name etc. in Oracle Identity Manager?

Tags: oracle, oim

I had logged in as xelsysadm in oracle identity manager and created different users, then i tried to create custom validation for fields such as telephone number and last name, but i don't know where to specify the regular expression and in what way the regular expression is to be specified. I had activated the sandbox,customized it and from the options i chose structure(located at the top left corner) and selected the telephone number column which is to be custom validated, then chose the corresponding tag for the telephone number column from right-side, then various display options were displayed such as VALUE, PARTIAL TRIGGERS etc, but i don't know where to specify the regular expression for validation and in what way it is to be mentioned.

I specified the below tag in VALUE field, but the result was not the expected.

af:validateRegExp pattern="/^+(\d+\s?)+$/"
Where to specify and how to specify the regular expression?

I specified af:validateRegExp pattern="/^+(\d+\s?)+$/" in the value field but it is not working as expected.

af:validateRegExp pattern="/^+(\d+\s?)+$/"

I expect the result to be like, when in future on creating a new user there should be strict validation for telephone number field like there must be a '+' sign in the beginning followed by numerical digits.

Comment: <af:validateRegExp pattern="/^+(\d+\s?)+$/"/>

Comment: you can make use of Validation event handler for multiple fields